# local variable 'script1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

Thank you in advance for you who could be able to help this. I spent many hours working on this error but can't figure it out. I am trying to use a form to grab a ticker and pass the ticker to a simple chart using bokeh and then deliver the result to views.py and display it on html. first of all I have the following code in my views.py.

```
def pme(request):
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
result = None
if request.method =='POST':
    form = InputForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        forms = form.save(commit=False)
        result = macd(forms.ticker)
        script1, div1 = components(result, CDN)
else:
    form = Ticker()

return render(request,'pme.html',
                          {"form":form,
                           "the_script1":script1,
                            "the_div1":div1,
                           })
```

For some reasons, script1 is referenced before?

my macd(forms.ticker) simply returns p and it works fine by itself.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at all the routes through your code. If the request is not  POST, or the form is not valid, then script1 and div1 are not defined; yet you still use them at the end of the function.

Either ensure that they are defined in all routes, or don't use them in the cases where they are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I need to include script1 = None . Once that's included I cleared the reference before assignment inbound error.